# Simple NG-IF filter not working with date but works with other data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

So I have simple ng-repeat with an ng-if filter that does not seem to work for DATE but works for everything else (like cal, time). I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Controller:

```
$scope.twoWeeksForward=new Date();
$scope.twoWeeksForward.setDate($scope.twoWeeksForward.getDate() - 14);

  $scope.sampledata = [
    { title: 'First Workout', time:1500 ,cal: 376, date: "2016-05-22T07:57:24.792Z"},
    { title: 'Second Workout', time:1100 ,cal: 20, date: 2016-05-22},
    { title: 'Third Workout', time:500 ,cal: 190, date: 01232016 },
    { title: 'Fourth Workout', time:4500 ,cal: 900, date: 01222016 }
  ];
```

HTML: (THIS PART DOES NOT WORK)

```
<div ng-repeat="items in sampledata" ng-if="{{items.date}}>{{twoWeeksForward}}">
```

I tested out some different syntax for the date field but nothing is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to figure how to implement function and ng-repeat...do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `{{}}` interpolation in `ng-if` ... it evaluates expressions directly. You are also missing a `"` to close the attribute value

Try

```
<div ng-repeat="items in sampledata" ng-if="items.date">
```

Comment: great...but how do i compare the two...this does not work ng-if="items.date<twoWeeksForward"

Comment: convert both values to date objects

Comment: I'm new to coding...could provide an example of how I would go about doing that within the ng-repeat...I tried using ng-init with a function but that didn't work

Comment: You need to iterate data in controller and convert dates there

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better using a custom filter function on your ng-repeat, rather than a second directive (ngIf) on the same element:

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="items in sampledata | filter:isNextTwoWeeks">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.isNextTwoWeeks = function(item) {
    return item.date && item.date > $scope.twoWeeksForward;
}
```

Note that the date comparison could do with some improvement and I'm not exactly sure of the logic you're trying to achieve so I just copied what you listed in your example.

Comment: The other option - if you only ever show data on that basis - is to just bind data that meets that criteria in your controller (i.e. filter out data that you don't want to display before you initialise the collection that you bind your view to).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct format for ng-if.

```
<div ng-repeat="date in sampledata" ng-if="{{toDate(date.date)< twoWeeksForward}}">
```

You need to convert the date in the scope variable to date format as currently it is not in it so follow this
and add **toDate** function in controller

```
$scope.toDate = function(date) {
   return new Date(date);
}
```